# How to invert only negative elements in numpy matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix containing positive and negative numbers like this:

```
>>> source_matrix
    array([[-4, -2,  0],
           [-5,  0,  4],
           [ 0,  6,  5]])
```

I'd like to had a copy of this matrix with inverted negatives:

```
>>> result
    array([[-0.25, -0.5,  0],
           [-0.2,  0,  4],
           [ 0,  6,  5]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, since your desired array is gonna contain float type you need to determine the array's `dtype` at creation time as `float`. The reason for that is because if you assign the float results of the inverted sub-array they'll automatically be casted to float. Secondly, you need to find the negative numbers in your array and then use a simple indexing in order to grab them and use `np.true_divide()` to perform the inversion.

```
In [25]: arr = np.array([[-4, -2,  0],
    ...:                 [-5,  0,  4],
    ...:                 [ 0,  6,  5]], dtype=np.float)
    ...:            
    ...:            

In [26]: mask = arr < 0

In [27]: arr[mask] = np.true_divide(1, arr[mask])

In [28]: arr
Out[28]: 
array([[-0.25, -0.5 ,  0.  ],
       [-0.2 ,  0.  ,  4.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  6.  ,  5.  ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this without masking, by using the `where` and `out` params of `true_divide`.

```
a = np.array([[-4, -2,  0],
              [-5,  0,  4],
              [ 0,  6,  5]], dtype=np.float)

np.true_divide(1, a, out=a, where=a<0)
```

Giving the result:

```
array([[-0.25, -0.5 ,  0.  ],
       [-0.2 ,  0.  ,  4.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  6.  ,  5.  ]])
```

The `where=` parameter is passed an array of the same dimensions as your two inputs. Where this evaluates to `True` the divide is performed. Where it evaluates to `False`, the original input, passed in via `out=` is output into the result unchanged.